# Is there a way to figure out which mefarshim to look at for parsha?

Tags: torah-study, chumash

A mikro'os gedolos chumash has several different mefarshim's explanations on each passuk of each parsha. Obviously every single word of these commentaries are unfathomably valuable to our understanding of the Torah, but for people on our level not every single pshat on every single passuk will necessarily inspire every single person. For example, explanation of certain grammar rules as they pertain to a passuk are critically important but for a casual reader won't necessarily result in inspiration and desire to be better. Is there a strategy or sefer that can help a reader know which mefarshim to look at for the more fundamental ideas in mefarshim?

Comment: you may like https://korenpub.co.il/products/parshaney-hamikra

Answer (score 3):

Rav Ahron Lopiansky compiled such a sefer, [יסודי התורה](https://www.eshelpublications.com/store/p3/Yesodei_Hatorah_2_Volume_Set.html)

The description says as follows:

A collection of the theological fundamental essays culled from the Rishonim, organized by Parsha.​

Answer (score 3):

[R' Akiva Weisinger](https://substack.com/profile/1921883-akiva-weisinger) started his [*Misfit Torah*](https://anchor.fm/misfit-torah) podcast with a series called "Who the heck is this guy?" (the first 11 episodes, published in 2018-2020) in which he describes the styles of the major commentaries on the Torah and provides guidance for when you might want to consult one or the other, in particular. I found this series very helpful for understanding the important differences between the commentaries.